# Return objects with ids matching the ids in another array mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having an issue running a query on my mongo DB. I want to return the objects that match the ids in the array of Ids. Not sure what I'm doing wrong everywhere online suggests doing it this exact way.

Mongoose Query

```
MovieSchema.statics.findKnownForMovies = function(ids) { return this.find({ id: { $in: [ids]}});
```

}

Mongoose Schema

```
    const MovieSchema = new Schema({
adult: { type: Boolean },
  category: {type: String},
  id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  poster_path: { type: String },
  overview: { type: String },
  release_date: { type: String },
  original_title: { type: String },
  genre_ids: [{ type: Number }],
  original_language: { type: String },
  title: { type: String },
  backdrop_path: { type: String },
  popularity: { type: Number },
  vote_count: { type: Number },
  video: { type: Boolean },
  vote_average: { type: Number })
```

Array of ids

```
[ '577922', '487558', '429203' ]
```

Comment: Please include the code you're having an issue with as text, it makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: Sorry I've edited my question

Comment: It seems `ids` is already array, so the query in find should be `{ id: { $in: ids}}`

Comment: You should also make sure the elements of the `ids` array are numbers, to match with your schema.